# What's the best way to align something but keep it responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Link to my code to see the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/0sbcdfLk/2/

I am using a bootstrap responsive login form template which I'm also using for the design of the logged in screen. I've copied the formContent section of the code twice so I now have 2 of the containers but I want the second one aligned to the left normally and directly below on mobile.

I can align it to the left with margin but that messes the design up on mobile. What is best practice for responsive design? This is the exact bootstrap template I am using https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/X2bG0

I have duplicated this part of the code

```
    <div id="formContent">
<!-- Tabs Titles -->

<!-- Icon -->
<div class="fadeIn first">
  <img src="https://www.b-cube.in/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/aditya-300x177.jpg" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
  <h1>Aditya News</h1>
</div>

<!-- Login Form -->
<form>
  <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="login" placeholder="username">
  <input type="text" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="login" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In">
</form>

<!-- Remind Passowrd -->
<div id="formFooter">
  <a class="underlineHover" href="#">Go to the Site</a>
</div>
```

I can add a style to the bottom one `margin: -50% 0px -6px -95%` which works fine for PC but mobile it basically is half off the screen and overflowing the first form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "CSS @media" rules. Break the CSS by width of the window.
You can define @media rules for different device screen sizes to suite mobile, tablets, PCs, wide screens. Using them you can manipulate everything like you normally would. 
Set class in HTML for the form content div (there're multiple IDs, classes are better for styling even if used once):

```
<div id="formContent" class="account-details">
```

Add media rule to display the form on the left when on wide enough screen:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
  .account-details{
    position: absolute !important;
    left: 0;
    margin-left: -150px;
  }
}
```

Edit: Working example https://jsfiddle.net/y2sgobLz/

Comment: This doesn't work because of the way I've done my code... I posted it on jsfiddle so you can see my problem and possibly tell me the better way of doing what I've done? Thanks for the information about media rules! I will look into that as it seems like it will be very helpful! https://jsfiddle.net/0sbcdfLk/2/

Comment: @JBower, did you want to achieve something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/y2sgobLz/ .HTML and CSS has changes. On PC it displays the card on the left, and on mobile displays underneath (default CSS).

Comment: That was perfect thank you! For some reason it broke my background but I just added the same code I had in html to just above the media query and used body and it worked! Will mark your answer as correct. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You're welcome. I've modified the answer to have the actual changes instead of suggestion and examples.